# compare program results on cpp and python

Tags: python, c++, testing

I would like to test `cpp` code using `Python`.

I have next code and `a.exe` file, which I get after complilation:

```
int main() {
    std::istream& input_stream = std::cin;
    std::ostream& output_stream = std::cout;
    Data input_data = ReadData(input_stream);
    Data output_data = DoSomethingWithData(input_data);
    OutputData(output_data, output_stream);
    return 0;
}
```

And I have `py` code:

```
input_data = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    input_data += line
output_data = do_something_with_data(input_data)
print(output_data)
```

I would like to make `py` script, which can give equal input to `cpp` programm and `py` programm and compare outputs. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
input_data = "some-data"
cpp_output = subprocess.check_output(["a.exe", input_data])
python_output = subprocess.check_output(["python", "test.py", input_data])
assert cpp_output == python_output
```

Comment: `assert` did not help to understand what the difference is. [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module may be useful in such case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using windows. I would redirect the output of both programs to a file and then compare files. In cmd.exe:

```
a.exe > a_output.txt
your_python_script.py > py_output.txt
FC a_output.txt py_output.txt
```

You can use ">" to redirect output to text. The command FC (File Compare) checks the differences between the files.